# Choosing hosting solution and deploy tool for Scala (Lift) based application

Tags: scala, deployment, hosting, lift, production-environment

I'm working on the web application based on Scala, Lift, MongoDB. Which hosting solution are you using for such apps? I have been thought about something easy like Heroku or even totally configured VPS.

What is most popular deploy tool in JVM/Scala world? E.g. I use Capistrano for Rails.

Comment: This question is very likely to get closed unless you add a lot more detail.  As asked, the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Xen-based VPS is a good choice for Java based applications. Java will not run good on a OpenVZ based VPS.

Ang you also have the alternative to use Google App Engine or Amazon.

Comment: What do you think about Linode.com and about plan "Linode 512"?